# Cannot find "item" in scope. SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, scope

Fairly new to SwiftUI so this is probably just something simple I'm missing.

Getting this error: "Cannot find '$interactionVM' in scope" where I'm trying to present the sheet.
This only occurs when I use .sheet, if I replace the sheet with Text(String(...)) I can access the values of interactionVM with no errors.

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    var interactionVM: InteractionViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    HomeViewCard()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $interactionVM.presentInteractionMenu) {
                    InteractionMenuView(interactionVM: interactionVM)
                        .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.2), .fraction(0.3), .fraction(0.4), .fraction(0.5), .fraction(0.6), .fraction(0.7), .fraction(0.8), .fraction(0.9)])
                        .interactiveDismissDisabled()
                        .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Menu {
                            NavigationLink {
                                EmptyView()
                            } label: {
                                Text("Option 1")
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    HomeView(interactionVM: InteractionViewModel())
}
```

The interactionVM is initialised in the root file and then passed to HomeView:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct theBlackBookApp: App {
    
    let interactionVM = InteractionViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            HomeView(interactionVM: interactionVM)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my interactionVM file as well in case it is relevant.

```
import Foundation

@Observable
class InteractionViewModel {
    var interactions: [Interaction] = [Interaction(interactionName: "Example", id: UUID())]
    
    var presentInteractionMenu: Bool = true
    var presentInteractionDetails: Bool = false
    
}
```

Any help or alternative solutions are greatly appreciated! I just need to be able to modify the Bool values from other views.

**Things I have tried:**

Checking and rechecking for typos,
Cleaning build folder and restarting Xcode,
Restarting Mac,
Deleting DerivedData from project file

Comment: In SwiftUI the `View` struct is the view model already you don't need a class for it and if you try you will have major issues like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@State` to initialize an `@Observable`

```
@State var interactionVM = InteractionViewModel()
```

and use `@Bindable` to modify it.

```
@Bindable var interactionVM: InteractionViewModel
```

The `$` is a a way of accessing a `Binding` that acts as a two-way connection with the source of truth and it comes from `DynamicProperty` that is used by the `@propertyWrapper`.

I suggest you look a the basic Apple SwiftUI tutorials.

Comment: Appreciate the super fast reply, this fixed the issue. Should @Bindable always be used where the VM is used, or only when it's being modified? I will definitely check out the tutorials as well, thanks for the help and suggestion.

Comment: @BabaD it isn't needed if you aren't modifying.